# Что такое валидация в ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

И зачем она нужна, объясните, пожалуйста, очень "разжевано".

Answer (score 1):

Я сам недавно начал разбираться и могу вам сказать, что валидация вещь достаточно нужная, и я бы даже сказал, необходимая. Валидация делается для того, чтобы с клиентской стороны не пришло какое-нибудь левое значение. Например, пустая строка или недопустимые символы для пароля. Пример: форма для входа на сайт, содержащая строчку для ввода имени и пароля. Вы валидируете 2 эти текстбокса. Допустим, пользователь оставил эти два текстбокса пустыми или заполнил только одно из них. Валидаторы для этих полей не позволят отправить ему запрос на сервер с этими данными (в моём примере это пустая строчка). Или пользователь ввёл символы кирилицы в поле пароля или какие-нибудь другие данные, которые могут скорить сервер или клиент. Тем самым валидаторы позволят вам отсечь изначально неправильные данные. Я понимаю это так.

Comment: имеется ввиду валидатор ASP.NET,я так понимаю он выполняется на сервере,так как является этапом жизненного цикла страницы aspx.В статье было написано,что он нужен для того чтоб злоумышленики не могли собирать информацию о сайте с помощью скриптов. Каким образом?

Answer (score 1):

Основной особенностью валидаторов ASP.NET является то, что валидация выполняется на клиенте, без отправки запроса на сервер. CustomValidator по умолчанию инициирует отправку запроса на сервер, но его можно настроить так, чтобы он выполнялся на клиенте (указав ему функцию javascript, проверяющую введённое значение).

Дальше интегральный результат валидации доступен через свойство Page.IsValid.

Валидаторы позволяют декларативно задать

- Что пользователь заполнил обязательные поля
- Что данные, введённые пользователем попадают в нужный диапазон
- Что строки, введённые пользователем, имеют нужный формат
- Любые проверки, написанные вручную.

Насколько я помню, все результаты валидации помещаются в специальный контрол, который будет располагаться в одном месте.

Comment: имеется ввиду валидатор ASP.NET,я так понимаю он выполняется на сервере,так как является этапом жизненного цикла страницы aspx.В статье было написано,что он нужен для того чтоб злоумышленики не могли собирать информацию о сайте с помощью скриптов. Каким образом?

Comment: Код, формирующий функцию javascript, проверяющую введённое пользователем значение, выполняется на сервере. Но сама эта функция перед отправкой запроса к серверу выполняется на клиенте.

Что касается защиты от злоумышленников, то тут скорее валидаторы не дадут сделать postback, пока страница не заполнена. Но это так себе защита, скорее, подспорье. Всё-таки основная цель валидаторов - это usability. Хотя, в приниципе, конечно же, с помощью валидатора можно сделать, например, капчу.

Answer (score 0):

Одним словом, валидатор проверяет, правильно ли ввел пользователь данные при регистрации на том или ином сайте или при входе на почту...